# .Net running on Linux

Tags: java, .net, linux

I heard that you can run a .net application on Linux machine.  The process is to take .net byte code and run it on a linux jvm.  Has anyone experience any problem with this?  Do you know of any specific bottleneck of doing so?

Comment: @Abius: That isn't true.  Only WinForms and WPF are heavily tied to Windows.  (although I've never used Mono)

Comment: Can the JVM run .NET byte code? That would certainly be news to me.

Comment: @Abius: Except for L2S, .Net is not tied to SQL Server at all.  In fact, Mono out-does .Net there.  http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6#LINQ_to_SQL

Comment: @AbiusX: What parts of .NET rely on MS SQL?

Comment: .NET doesn't but most of .NET apps does. Its Microsoft world.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better process and that is to use the [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) runtime.

Mono is:

> An open source, cross-platform, implementation of C# and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft.NET

And it runs on linux.

It is not perfect, as there are some windows specific namespaces in .NET that simply do not have a Linux equivalent (WMI, WPF are a couple of examples).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). You can run .Net projects on many OSes, including MacOS, Linux, Solaris and Windows (!).

Not all of .Net is supported by Mono. The [Mono Migration Analysis](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) tool can help here.